# Why do I get this error when installing the NestJS Client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nestjs

I have the following error when trying to install the nestjs client, I honestly do not understand this error.

```
PS C:\Users\meuser> npm i -g @nestjs/cli
    npm ERR! code ETARGET
    npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular-devkit/core@12.2.10.
    npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
    npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\meuser\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-22T15_23_52_127Z-debug.log
```

Here I leave my versions and my packages installed. But I do not know why in the installation it does not find the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/core/v/12.2.10

```
PS C:\Users\meuser> npm -v
7.24.1
PS C:\Users\meuser> node -v
v12.18.4
PS C:\Users\meuser> npm list -g
C:\Users\meuser\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @angular/cli@12.2.7
+-- @vue/cli@4.5.13
+-- create-react-app@3.4.1
+-- npm@7.24.1
+-- typescript@4.4.3
+-- vsts-npm-auth@0.41.0
`-- yarn@1.22.11
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your node version?
Also, a workaround could be changing @angular-devkit/core@12.2.10 into @angular-devkit/core. This will try to find a matching version of the dependency to your environment specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall nodejs and it solved the problem